# Getting '{success: false, errorMessage: "Error: Invalid request."}' when calling sforce.console.getPrimaryTabIds()

Tags: service-cloud-console, tab, custom-console-components, sforce

We have a Visualforce console component. At some point, we want to get info about all the open Console tabs. So we call

```
sforce.console.getPrimaryTabIds(function(result) { console.log(result); });
```

The function itself executes fine, but we get this result

```
{success: false, errorMessage: "Error: Invalid request."}
```

I can't seem to figure out what is happening. Has anyone seen this before or have a pointer as to what might be going on?

Comment: @Williem were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi @JefersonChaves I've stopped working with Salesforce altogether, but I remember that it only worked in a user-initiated event like a click but not in e.g. a setTimeout() call... But I think it's 'suggested' to build things as Lightning Components anyway so I would not wait/hope for this to be fixed by Salesforce

Comment: Thanks a million @Williem, fair enough.