# Why are calls to the service console integration toolkit failing on some browsers?

Tags: visualforce, consoleintegrationtoolkit, service-console

I have the following code on a visualforce page which I view through the Service Console, the idea being to close this tab and navigate to another.

```
    sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId(function (result) {
        sforce.console.closeTab(result.id);
    });
    sforce.one.navigateToSObject('{!myId}','RELATED');
```

This occasionally fails where the result.id returned by `getEnclosingTabId` is undefined. The navigate by `sforce.one.navigateToSObject('{!myId}','RELATED')` always works.

The reordering of the calls doesn't fix it.

I've tried upgrading my browsers to latest Chrome and Firefox. Also I **can't** get this to fail on any browser on BrowserStack; maybe there is a clue here - slower environment, better network.

Comment: The only time `getEnclosingTabId` will return undefined is if that tab is closed.

Comment: Have you checked the `result.error` on callback of `sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId`?

Comment: Hi Jeferson, there are two parameters on the result `errorMessage: "Error: Invalid request."` and `success: false`

Comment: That is interesting and good to know. It seems to be similar to this [one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301928/getting-success-false-errormessage-error-invalid-request-when-calling).